# Looking for a recommendation for an OS X Bash manual

Tags: macos, bash, documentation

I've just begun to use the Terminal in Mac OS X and I've found the `man` command very useful, although very often the explanations are too compact or complicated for me. I am looking for a very basic reference guide – like O'Reilly makes, for example. But in there I didn't find an entry for basic commands like `ls` or `ln` and a layman's explanation of all the flags and options.

Could anybody recommend me something?

Answer (score 2):

If a video tutorial is more your style, Dan Benjamin did a 2-part intro to the command line that is very well structured. Part 1 is here:

http://peepcode.com/products/meet-the-command-line

And part 2 (with Geoffrey Grosenbach) is here:

http://peepcode.com/products/advanced-command-line

There appear to be free previews of the screencasts here:

http://peepcode.com/system/uploads/2009/peepcode-034-cmdline-preview.mov

http://peepcode.com/system/uploads/2009/peepcode-037-advanced-cmd-preview.mov

Hope this is helpful!

(Note that I have no relationship with Peepcode or Dan Benjamin other than being admirers of this piece of work…)

Comment: Bought those videos, and like them, but I don't remember being in-depth about flags of certain commands (i.e. what the user wants).

Comment: Moved to http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/meet-command-line

Answer (score 0):

[The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org) has very good (although slightly dated) documentation for many Linux/Unix tools. They have a [bash beginner's guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/), a [bash programming guide](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) and an [advanced bash-scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) which should cover most aspects of bash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Mac OS at all, but for an intro to unix commands I like this link:

http://lnag.sourceforge.net/lnag_html/node5.html

Skip the first section for moving around linux

Regards,

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

Find an ancient book on Unix, preferably from the '80s or even late 70s, when Unix and the shell were brand new concepts.  If you buy 
[http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Dummies-John-R-Levine/dp/0764541471/ref=pd_sim_sbs_b_5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764541471) 
used, you'll pay more for shipping than for the actual item, which makes sense for
something like this (and its author, John Levine, is well regarded in the Unix
community).

Every command has grown more command-line options since these books were published,
so at some point you'll need to turn to the man pages for more of an explanation.
But then you'll reach a point where you can resell the book, and the man pages alone
will be perfectly fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

[This is the official manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html), which is probably on your system and accessible using `info bash`.

The [Official FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ) can be very useful.

The resources at [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/EnglishFrontPage) are invaluable. Particularly:

- [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ)
- [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)
- [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)
- [Pages in CategoryShell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CategoryShell)

Answer (score 0):

While this link isn't `bash` specific, you'll find these manuals written by the folks that wrote `unix` invaluable-

http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/bswv7.html